# migration issue from Package by Layer to -> Package by Feature

Tags: java, spring-boot, package, refactoring

- What I am trying to achieve

I wish to use "Package by Feature" for my @Configuration files.
Currently, I am using "Package by Layer".
Just to be clear, this is not an opinion-based question of type which is better between "Package by Feature" and "Package by Layer", but rather a question on how to properly migrate.

- This is the current code structure:

Package by layer:

```
├── com.app
    └── configuration
        ├── KafkaProducerConfiguration
        ├── MongoRepositoryConfiguration
        └── RestClientConfiguration
    └── controller
        ├── CompanyController
        ├── ProductController
        └── UserController
    └── model
        ├── Company
        ├── Product
        └── User
    └── repository
        ├── CompanyRepository
        ├── ProductRepository
        └── UserRepository
    └── service
        ├── CompanyService
        ├── ProductService
        └── UserService
```

The kafka producer is needed by the company service to send messages to other parts of the company.
The rest client is needed by the user service and the product service to query some external information.
the mongo repository is needed to configure all three classes in the repository layer.

- What I tried:

Following this guide: https://medium.com/sahibinden-technology/package-by-layer-vs-package-by-feature-7e89cde2ae3a

I am refactoring to this:

```
├── com.app
    └── configuration
        ├── KafkaProducerConfiguration
        ├── MongoRepositoryConfiguration
        └── RestClientConfiguration
    └── company
        ├── Company
        ├── CompanyController
        ├── CompanyRepository
        └── CompanyService
    └── product
        ├── Product
        ├── ProductController
        ├── ProductRepository
        └── ProductService
    └── user
        ├── User
        ├── UserController
        ├── UserRepository
        └── UserService
```

- Issue:

Unfortunately, I am facing difficulties in refactoring the configuration layer, and I would like to avoid a hybrid package by feature + package by layer.

- Question:

How to refactor this configuration layer into the "Package by feature"?

Comment: Please explain what difficulty you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

In my perception this is a question about how to organize package structure, there are general two directions, first is divide by business logic, through key business logic concept to finish package structure organize, second is divide by domain, use DDD(Domain-driven design) to divide domain and around domain to organize package structure. but both of those are subjective, it not have a standard answer

Comment: Better to vote to close as opinion based.